Boost multiprecision library
Boost multiprecision libraries highest value possible
Can the boost multiprecision handle values as large as googolplex , like maybe the boost multiprecision cpp dec float library?
So can someone please tell me the largest value possible in any boost multiprecision library?

It depends on the physical resources of your machine

Ok so  i have 64 gb ram can i handle values larger than googolplex?

I shouldn't think so. The binary representation of 10^(10^100) would require approximately 4.1524×10^99 bytes, a storage need far beyond the capacity of the physical universe.

cpp_dec_float would have been your best bet, solely because the base-10 mantissa is always 1 for googol(plex). However, the exponent type is required to be a builtin integer type. std::int128_t doesn't even qualify if the compiler supports it. So, that's right off.
Using GMP backends appears to break down at 5e+17 digits:
#include <boost/multiprecision/gmp.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    using namespace boost::multiprecision;

    using Real = mpf_float;
    using Int  = mpz_int;

    // create a googolplex
    Int googol = pow(Int(10), 100u);

    // print it
    std::cout << googol << std::endl;
    std::cout << "check: " << log10(Real(googol)) << std::endl;

    // no plex for you
    auto not_googolplex = pow(Real(10), Real("5e17"));
    std::cout << "check: " << log10(not_googolplex) << std::endl;

    not_googolplex = pow(Real(10), Real("5e18"));
    std::cout << "check: " << log10(not_googolplex) << std::endl;
}

Printing (on my AMD64 64GiB box using GCC14 or Clang18 and Boost 1.86):
10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
check: 100
check: 5e+17
GNU MP: Cannot allocate memory (size=4611686018427387960)
Aborted (core dumped)


Oh ok thanks, got it.
